# How to scroll all flatlists nested in a section list?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have a FlatList nested in a SectionList as shown below.
There is always 3 sections (rows) and each section has a FlatList with a horizontal scroll.

**Expected**

On button click, invoking the scrollToEnd() function, to scroll all 3 flatlists from each section to end.

**Problem**

Only the bottom or last flatlist scrolls to the end.

I cannot figure out why this is - I thought the ref in the flatlist may only be referencing the last Flatlist rendered and not the other two, maybe? If so, any tips or suggestions are welcome.  Thank you.

```
             ...

             const flatlistRef = useRef();

             const scrollToEnd = () => {
                flatlistRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animating: true });
             };
             
             ...

             <SectionList
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.sectionListContainer}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                    sections={myData}
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
                        <>
                            <FlatList
                                horizontal
                                data={section.data}
                                contentContainerStyle={
                                    styles.flatlistContainer
                                }
                                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                    <Button
                                        onPress={() => updateData(item.id)}
                                    >
                                        <ListItem item={item} />
                                    </Button>
                                )}
                                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                ref={flatlistRef}
                            />
                        </>
                    )}
                    renderItem={({}) => {
                        return null;
                    }}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also working on this but I found a solution where I can create a **Section.List** by using **react-native-paper**.

But you can also use the **map** function, Here is the code of that

```
 import React from "react";
 import {View,Text} from "react-native";

 const App = () =>{
     return(
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
     {data.map((item, index) => (
         <View key={index} style={{borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
             <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.title}</Text>
             {item.items && <>
             {item.items.map((item, index) => (
                 <View key={index} style={{backgroundColor: '#7fc', borderBottomColor: 'blue', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 40, color: 'blue'}}>{item.title}</Text>
                      {item.items && <>
                      {item.items.map((item, index) => (
                        <View key={index}  style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', borderBottomColor: 'red', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginLeft: 80,}}>{item.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                     ))}
                    </>}
                </View>
             ))}
            </>}
         </View>
      ))}
 </View>
     )
 }
 export default App;
```

I hope It will help.

Comment: Unfortunately the section list will have to remain due to some formatting of data to allow it to render as expected.  If I replace the sectionlist, I'd also have to change the format of data.  Thank you for the suggestion though.